# Python Requests/Selenium with BeautifulSoup not returning find_all every time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to webscrape Airbnb, I had working code but it seems they have updated everything on the page. It intermittently returns the correct output and then sometimes it fails? It will return the NoneType error between the 3rd and 17th page randomly. Is there a way for it to keep trying or is my code incorrect?

```
for page in range(1,pages + 1):
        #get page urls
        page_url= url + '&page={0}'.format(page)
        print(page_url)


        #get page
        # browser.get(page_url)
        source = requests.get(page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

        #get all listings on page 
        div = soup.find('div',{'class':'row listing-cards-row'})



        #loop through to get all info needed from cards
        for pic in div.find_all('div',{'class':'listing-card-wrapper'}):
                  print(...)
```

the last for loop is where my error starts to occur. This happens sometimes in my other functions too where it sometimes works sometimes doesn't. I have already given lxml parser a try as well.

Comment: I would like to find a solution as requests is much faster but i resorted to using selenium and now everything seems to be running correctly. Slowly...but correctly.

Comment: one thing i have noticed that is odd even with selenium is that every time i change my code it will fail with the same error as the requests module the first time but after that it works flawlessly.

Comment: What is the error that you receiving? You should check that the page_url is received properly, like: `source.raise_for_status()` before you continue with the soup.

Comment: Christos, Im am receiving a nonetype error for find_all. But I finally discovered after looking through the soup a couple of times that the source code tags change about every 2 times requests fetches the page. This seemed to be my problem as i can now use requests and Selenium flawlessly. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the soup a couple of times i noticed that every couple of times the program would run the source code tags would change. I threw in some exceptions and it seems to have fixed my "None" issue.